# Camera movement

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I want to make an app where, if a person is in front of the phone a video show up, so, im trying to detect any movement on the camera to play the video or take two photos and analyze the pictures to know if something is different.

I wonder if that can be done with appcelerator/titanium, the app is for iOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

The one way I can think of doing this would be to take a photo at interval (every second maybe) then use something like resemble.js (http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) or something like this (https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images#JavaScript) to determine the difference in images and then decide what to do with that.

You can use appcelerator to take photos every x seconds, then process them, see http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media-method-takePicture.  Not sure how fast it would be, but I think it's doable...

Ray

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried resemble on my localhost and works like a charm then i tried to adapt the code to appcelerator and i got a lot of errors, i can`t use document., getContext() and a lot of things like that